# Default Spinner icon in grid cell

Tags: ag-grid

I need to do async call and load value in each cell of one particular column and refresh the row once the value is available from the server. I want to have a loading spinner in the cell when grid got initialized and once the value for that particular row is available I need to replace the loading spinner icon with new value from the server. Right now I am using cellRenderer for passing data because I need to show the data in .

Comment: Great details btw, but show everyone what have you done by urself and then it would be simpler to help you.